# Using AWS S3 c++ SDK with a custom endpoint

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk

I'm trying to use the AWS C++ SDK with a custom S3 compatible endpoint such as a minio server server instance.

I am trying to do something similar with what is done [here](https://docs.minio.io/docs/how-to-use-aws-sdk-for-go-with-minio-server) only that I need to do this with the  C++ SDK instead. I went through their documentation but I was unable to find any method that allows me to do this.

Is something like this supported ? If so, then some code samples could be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Figured this out. The endpointOverride option can be used to connect to a custom endpoint.