# AWS-C++ - Uploading to S3 is super slow on files larger than 5GB

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services

It is important to be said that this is executed on Windows.

Here is my code:

FileHandler.h:

```
#ifndef BEASTBURST_FILEHANDLER_H
#define BEASTBURST_FILEHANDLER_H
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <aws/core/Aws.h>
#include <aws/s3/S3Client.h>
#include <aws/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.h>
#include <aws/core/utils/memory/stl/AWSStreamFwd.h>

namespace BeastBurstCLI
{
    class FileHandler {
    public:
        FileHandler() : options{}
        {
            options.loggingOptions.logLevel = Aws::Utils::Logging::LogLevel::Trace;
            Aws::InitAPI(options);
            config_ = new Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration; // Allocate on the heap
            config_->region = Aws::Region::EU_CENTRAL_1;
        }
        ~FileHandler();
        bool PutObject(const Aws::String &bucketName,
                       const Aws::String &filePath,
                       const Aws::String &destinationPath);
    private:
        void MyDataSentEventHandler(const Aws::Http::HttpRequest* request, long long bytesSent);
        Aws::SDKOptions options;
        Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration* config_;
        std::mutex gMutex;
        bool gUploadComplete = false;
        long long gBytesSent = 0;
        long long gTotalBytes = 0;
        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point startTime;
    };
}



#endif //BEASTBURST_FILEHANDLER_H
```

FileHandler.cpp:

```
#include "FileHandler.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "aws/s3-encryption/s3Encryption_EXPORTS.h"

BeastBurstCLI::FileHandler::~FileHandler()
{
    Aws::ShutdownAPI(options);
    delete config_;
}


void BeastBurstCLI::FileHandler::MyDataSentEventHandler(const Aws::Http::HttpRequest *request, long long int bytesSent)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(gMutex);
    gBytesSent += bytesSent;
}


bool BeastBurstCLI::FileHandler::PutObject(const Aws::String &bucketName, const Aws::String &filePath,
                                           const Aws::String &destinationPath) {
    gUploadComplete = false;
    gBytesSent = 0;
    gTotalBytes = 0;

    Aws::S3::S3Client s3_client(config_);

    Aws::S3::Model::PutObjectRequest request;
    request.SetServerSideEncryption(Aws::S3::Model::ServerSideEncryption::AES256);
    request.SetBucket(bucketName);

    // Extract the file name from the full file path
    Aws::String fileName = Aws::Utils::StringUtils::Split(filePath, '/').back();
    Aws::String objectKey = destinationPath + "/" + fileName;
    request.SetKey(objectKey);

    std::shared_ptr<Aws::IOStream> inputData =
            Aws::MakeShared<Aws::FStream>("SampleAllocationTag",
                                          filePath.c_str(),
                                          std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);

    if (!*inputData) {
        std::cerr << "Error unable to read file " << filePath << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    // Get the total size of the file for calculating progress
    gTotalBytes = inputData->rdbuf()->pubseekoff(0, std::ios::end, std::ios::in);
    inputData->rdbuf()->pubseekpos(0, std::ios::in);

    request.SetDataSentEventHandler([this](const Aws::Http::HttpRequest* request, long long bytesSent) {
        MyDataSentEventHandler(request, bytesSent);
    });
    request.SetBody(inputData);

    startTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    std::thread progressThread([this]() {
        while (!gUploadComplete) {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(gMutex);
            double progressMB = gBytesSent / (1024.0 * 1024.0); // Convert bytes to megabytes
            double totalMB = gTotalBytes / (1024.0 * 1024.0); // Convert total bytes to megabytes

            std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point currentTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
            std::chrono::duration<double> elapsedSeconds = currentTime - startTime;
            double uploadSpeed = progressMB / elapsedSeconds.count(); // Calculate average speed

            if ((int)progressMB > 0) {
                std::cout << "Progress: " << (int)(progressMB * 100.0 / totalMB) << "% (" << (int)progressMB << "MB sent out of " << (int)totalMB << "MB), ";
                std::cout << "Speed: " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << uploadSpeed << " MB/s" << std::endl;
            }
        }
    });

    Aws::S3::Model::PutObjectOutcome outcome = s3_client.PutObject(request);

    gUploadComplete = true;
    progressThread.join(); // Wait for the progress thread to finish

    if (!outcome.IsSuccess()) {
        std::cerr << "Error: PutObject: " <<
                  outcome.GetError().GetMessage() << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Added object '" << fileName << "' to bucket '"
                  << bucketName << "' at path '" << destinationPath << "'." << std::endl;
    }

    return outcome.IsSuccess();
}
```

If I run `FileHandler::PutObject` on a file that is smaller than 5GB, it uploads with high speed, and it finishes the upload normally.

If I try to upload a file that is larger than 5GB, I receive mediocre uploads speeds like 0.4MB/s, and my upload always fails with message:

```
Error: PutObject: Encountered network error when sending http request
```

If I try to upload the same big file over the web browser to S3, all goes normal, it uploads with high speed. So I am sure something is wrong in my code.

I have enabled Transfer acceleration in my bucket, but I don't know if it is possible to enable it on the client via aws-cpp sdk. Is it even possible?

Why is this different behaviour based on the file size that I am uploading? What in my code is wrong?

Comment: *If I try to upload a file that is larger than 5GB* -- Is your application 32-bit or 64-bit?  That's the first thing that comes to mind seeing issues with a value larger than 4GB.

Comment: My application is Qt Console app and It is 64 bit.

Comment: To use Transfer Acceleration, I believe that you need to use the acceleration endpoint (e.g. bucketname.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.co for IPv4) using [endpointOverride](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43001748/using-aws-s3-c-sdk-with-a-custom-endpoint)?

Comment: PutObject is a wrapper around the PutObject REST API, which has a [hard 5GB limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/upload-objects.html).  I'd recommend using [TransferManager](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/cpp/example_code/transfer-manager/transferOnStream.cpp) which will use multipart uploads along with multithreading to upload larger objects.

Comment: @AnonCoward can you show me example of how to use TransferManager ?

Comment: The second link in my message is such an example.